# knapsack probl_m with transition cost

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, knapsack-problem

I am playing a game where you can program the IA of a leek to fight other leeks (leekwars, quite entertaining).

A leek has some action points per turn, let's say 10.

It has a range of weapon dealing damage D for a cost of C action point.
For example, pistol: 20 damage for 3 action points, etc.

It has a range of spells, similar to weapons. For example, spark: 16 damage for 3 action points.

I would like to deal maximum damage during my turn.

I thought this was a simple knapsack problem when I discovered that:

*Before using a weapon, you need to equip it, and that costs 1 action point. You do not need to re-equip it to re-use it afterwards, but you need to 1 action point to change weapon.* Any spell can be used without equipping it.

I have been trying, without success, to formalize this as a knapsack-like or linear programming problem.

My main idea would be to introduce for example a weapon `first_pistol` dealing 3 damage for 3+1 action points, and introduce the constraint (C1) that first_pistol can be used only once and (C2) that `pistol` can only be used if `first_pistol` has been used. But I am not sure how to formalize (C2).

Would you have any alternative approaches or comments on my approach?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a knapsack problem, this sounds like a scheduling problem to me!
You have a 'machine' that is working for 10 ('time') units (action points).
Different 'products' (weapons) have different process times (their action points).
In case you switch 'product types' (weapons) you incur a setup time of 1.
The underlying scheduling model will actually be quite basic, so look up some standard LP formulations :)

Comment: I guess the saying "When all you have is hammer, everything looks like a nail" just applied to me! Thanks, I will look up some litterature on job scheduling.